# When is the exception javax.persistence.PersistenceException thrown

Tags: database, hibernate

I was learning hibernate, and had encountered the exception - javax.persistence.PersistenceException
But I did not understand the exact reason for this.
In which scenarios is this exception thrown?

Answer (score 3):

PersistenceException occur with DB operations using EntityManager.

**Scenarios:**

- *EntityNotFoundException* => Entity does not exist.  eg. you are trying
  to find UserData but there is no Table with such name
- *NonUniqueResultException* => Thrown by the persistence provider when
  getSingleResult() is executed on a query and there is more than one
  result from the query.
  eg: em.getSingleResult().  but query more
  than 1 rows
- *NoResultException* => Thrown by the persistence provider when
  Query.getSingleResult() or TypedQuery.getSingleResult()is executed on
  a query and there is no result to return.

and Many more...

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/persistence/javadoc-1_0-fr/javax/persistence/PersistenceException.html

Answer (score 0):

PersistenceException is a Runtime Exception within JPA which may be thrown on calling entityManager's DB operations ex. find, persist, flush, lock, refresh, etc. This exception is the parent of following Exceptions :

EntityExistsException, EntityNotFoundException, NonUniqueResultException, NoResultException, OptimisticLockException, RollbackException, TransactionRequiredException.

You may use PersistenceException in order to catch any of the above exceptions in 
your DAO classs.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a datatype mismatch from database table to jpa i got this error
Ex: in table the date datatype(trandate) was given as varchar2 and i was assigning it to the date object and trying to convert date to String.

```
@Transactional
    public List<BulkTransferVwbulktransferAgent> getAgentList(String mode,String distributor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List<Object> query =null;
        if (mode.equalsIgnoreCase("I") || mode.equalsIgnoreCase("O"))
         {
             query = (List<Object>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select a.agent,a.agentmnemonic,a.status,a.agentGroup from "
                    + "BulkTransferVwbulktransferAgent a where a.status IS NULL and a.distributor =:p_distributor")
                    .setParameter("p_distributor", distributor).list();
         }
         List<BulkTransferVwbulktransferAgent> list=  new ArrayList<BulkTransferVwbulktransferAgent>();
         for (Iterator it = query.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
             BulkTransferVwbulktransferAgent vwbulktransferAgent =  new BulkTransferVwbulktransferAgent();
                Object[] myResult = (Object[]) it.next();
                String agent = (String) myResult[0];
                String agentmnemonic = (String) myResult[1];
                String status = (String) myResult[2];
                String agentGroup = (String) myResult[3];

                vwbulktransferAgent.setAgent(agent);
                vwbulktransferAgent.setAgentmnemonic(agentmnemonic);
                vwbulktransferAgent.setStatus(status);
                vwbulktransferAgent.setAgentGroup(agentGroup);

                list.add(vwbulktransferAgent);
            }
          return list;
    }
```

and sorry for the alignment i am posting answwer for the first time please guide me if its wrong..